# Using global variables in JIT yields garbage result

Tags: llvm

I'm using the llvm-c API and want to use the JIT. I've created the following module

```
; ModuleID = '_tmp'

@a = global i64 5

define i64 @__tempfunc() {
entry:
  %a_val = load i64* @a
  ret i64 %a_val
}
```

This output is generated by *LLVMDumpModule* just before I call *LLVMRunFunction*. Which yields a *LLVMGenericValueRef*. However converting the result to a 64bit integer via *LLVMGenericValueToInt(gv, true)*, it results in 360287970189639680 or something similar - not 5. Converting via *LLVMGenericValueToInt(gv, false)* didn't help either.

How can I use global variables in a JIT situation? Is anything wrong with the IR?

Edit: Well, i figured out that it has to do with the datalayout, since 360287970189639680 actually is 0x50...0. So I'd like to change the question to "How do I set the correct datalayout for a module? I've tried: *LLVMSetDataLayout(mod, "x86_64-pc-linux")* which aborts my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data layout format is described in http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout. And it's certainly not a target triple. Best, if you would simply feed dummy .c file to clang for your target, compile via -S -emit-llvm and grab the full data layout string from there.